# Why is read replica on Elasticache Redis instance not showing handling any read requests?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I have an AWS Elasticache Redis instance with 2 nodes - primary and a read replica. I'm connecting to the instance using `StackExchange.Redis`.

The `databases` value passed to the constructor is a comma separated string containing both the primary endpoint and the reader endpoint.

```
public class RedisCacheConnectionFactory : IRedisCacheConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> _connector;

    public RedisCacheConnectionFactory(string databases)
    {
        var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse(databases);
        options.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
        options.SyncTimeout = 1000;
        this._connector = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options));
    }

    public ConnectionMultiplexer Connection() => this._connector.Value;
}
```

It looks like no read requests are going to the read replica and they are all hitting the primary instance.

[image: Cloudwatch logs showing no reads to read replica]

I was under the impression that read replicas would help share the load of read requests to increase throughput. Why are no read requests showing against the read replica?

Comment: have you found a answer to this??

Comment: I have same question. Do we need to explicitly provide aws redis replica instance connection string in endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to specify both the Master and Replica endpoints to the Redis configuration on your redis client.
2. There is a flag for Redis commands that allows you to control replica usage.  The default implementation prefers Master. You'd need to explicitly specify the optional `CommandFlags` param to either `CommandFlags.PreferSlave` or `CommandFlags.PreferReplica` (looks like they are both set to the same value).

See here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1363#issuecomment-590592408

and

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/8612fb8a9278822c87d5476819325a7438e596ca/src/StackExchange.Redis/Enums/CommandFlags.cs#L53